# CakePHP 2.0 alternative for Configure::getInstance?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm currently trying to migrate from CakePHP 1.3 to 2.0.
Do you know an alternative for Configure::getInstance() that works in CakePHP 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cake 2.x uses AclExtras as explaind in http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/part-two.html to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you used `Configure::getInstance()` in CakePHP 1.3, but all methods of the `Configure` class in CakePHP 2.0 are static, so you can call them with `Configure::<METHOD_NAME>`.

Comment: I'm trying to adapt the code I used from [link](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1549/An-Automated-tool-for-creating-ACOs). `Configure::getInstance` is used to get paths:  `$paths = Configure::getInstance();`

Comment: I think you can ignore this snippet because in the linked code the `$paths` variable is never used after the assignment.

Comment: thanks, now I know why it worked after I changed `$paths = Configure::getInstance` to `$paths = Configure::bootstrap()` :D